# hide a div using javascript using if statement

Tags: javascript, session, xhtml

I want to hide a div with id apDiv1 using javascript when the values are not equal, I am using the following code.But it is not working.

```
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (#{sessionScope['userdet']['email']}!=#{sessionScope['frienddet']['email']}){
$('#apDiv1').hide();
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

The rendered code is as follows:

```
<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    if (amlan@ymail.com != atinr4@gmail.com){
     $('#apDiv1').hide();
    }
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered code is not valid JS - you've got a syntax error on the `if` condition because you need to quote the strings that contain the email addresses. That is, your rendered code should look like this:

```
if ("amlan@ymail.com" != "atinr4@gmail.com"){
```

Or you can use single quotes, JS allows either (as long as they match for any particular string literal).

I don't know what your source language is, but I assume you could get the rendered result that you need with something like this:

```
if ("#{sessionScope['userdet']['email']}"!="#{sessionScope['frienddet']['email']}"){
```

**EDIT:** Have you included the jquery.js file on your page? You didn't use the jquery tag on your question, but the `$("#apDiv1").hide()` part uses jQuery functions `$()` and `.hide()`. If you don't have jQuery try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("apDiv1").style.display = "none";
```

Also, the code you've shown will only be able to find the div if the script block appears after it, or if you wrap your code in a document ready handler as follows (though this also assumes jQuery is available):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // your other code here    
});
```

Non-jQuery version using an onload handler:

```
window.onload = function() {

    // your other code here
};
```

Comment: After applying the quotes the rendered code look like this`if ("amlan@ymail.com" != "atinr4@gmail.com"){
$('#apDiv1').hide();
}` but still the div is showing :(

Comment: Can you check if there is anywhere else where the $('#apDiv1').show() is present, maybe in pageLoad or Document.Ready.
there might be something that shows the div after being hidden.

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow for a few other issues. Are you using jQuery as implied by the code in your question?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {

    // your code here

});` this solved my problem, the script was before the div tag so it was not working

Answer (score 1):

you need enclose the 2 (email)values in quotes